# USER1: Initializing port 0 EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1 Cause: Cannot setup TX queue; port=0, err=Invalid argument (fastcapa)

Tags: apache-kafka, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04, dpdk, librdkafka

i am trying to run fastcapa (metron project) on VM(ubuntu20.04) with dpdk and librdkafka installed and built.
but when i run this commande i got this error:
cmnd: `sudo ./fastca                                                                                                                                  pa -c 0x0f -n 1 --huge-dir /mnt/huge_1GB -- -p 0x00 -t pcap -c /etc/project/metr                                                                                                                                  on/metron-sensors/fastcapa/conf/fastcapa.conf` 
error:

```
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
EAL: PCI device 0000:0b:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
EAL: PCI device 0000:13:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15ad:7b0 net_vmxnet3
[ -p PORT_MASK ] defined as -1
[ -b RX_BURST_SIZE ] defined as 32
[ -w TX_BURST_SIZE ] defined as 256
[ -d NB_RX_DESC ] defined as 1024
[ -x TX_RING_SIZE ] defined as 2048
[ -q NB_RX_QUEUE ] defined as 1
[ -t KAFKA_TOPIC ] defined as pcap
[ -c KAFKA_CONFIG ] defined as /etc/project/metron/metron-sensors/fastcapa/conf/                                                                                                                                  fastcapa.conf
[ -s KAFKA_STATS ] defined as (null)
[ NUM_RX_WORKERS ] defined as 1
[ NUM_TX_WORKERS ] defined as 2
USER1: config[kafka-global]: metadata.broker.list = localhost:9092
USER1: config[kafka-global]: client.id = fastcapa
USER1: config[kafka-global]: batch.num.messages = 500000
USER1: config[kafka-global]: queue.buffering.max.messages = 5000000
USER1: config[kafka-global]: metadata.broker.list = localhost:9092
USER1: config[kafka-global]: client.id = fastcapa
USER1: config[kafka-global]: batch.num.messages = 500000
USER1: config[kafka-global]: queue.buffering.max.messages = 5000000
%3|1614601657.361|FAIL|fastcapa#producer-2| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: loc                                                                                                                                  alhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused
%3|1614601657.361|FAIL|fastcapa#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: loc                                                                                                                                  alhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused

USER1: Initializing port 0
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Cannot setup TX queue; port=0, err=Invalid argument
```

can someone help to solve this issue.
thank you.

Comment: Show your conf file... `port=0, err=Invalid argument` seems self-explanatory... Plus, is Kafka actually running?

Comment: @refkabenmarzouk in your applciation the arguemtn is passed as `-p 0x00 `. This stands for no ports. Ideally the application should check for `rte_eth_dev_count_avail() & portmask != 0` then proceed for initialization, but as per your logs it does not. SO please fix your port mask and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As per [metron github](https://github.com/apache/metron/tree/master/metron-sensors/fastcapa) link, the sample command suggested is

> fastcapa -c 0x03 --huge-dir /mnt/huge_1GB -- -p 0x01 -t pcap -c /etc/fastcapa.conf

where the port mask is set as `-p 0x01`. In your current application run the port maks is set as zero.

Comment: thnx for help the problem was in nic.c code. i fixed this issue, it sends the messages but throws errors while starting : kafka client error; conn=fastcapa#producer-1, error=Local: Broker transport failure [localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused]

Comment: Happy to hear you were able to solve the issue., not sure why poirt mak is `-p 0x0` was set to 0.

Comment: it's not a probelm since port 0 is used as default so i can put it 0x00 or 0x01